# Polarion SDK: Get document name in workflow context

Tags: sdk, alm, polarion

I am working on a word roundtrip script, which is triggered in a workflowContext.

Following object from Polarion SDK I have used so far:

> workflowContext (com.polarion.alm.tracker.workflow.ICallContext)

My Code to grab the document is:

```
var module = workflowContext.getTarget();
```

Now I also would like to get the name of the "Target". I tried several approaches, such as:

```
var modulename = workflowContext.getTarget().getName(); //doesn't work
```

but they all failed. Typical Error Message:

> javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError:
>   workflowContext.getTarget().getName is not a function in < eval > at
>   line number 33

That's why I would like to know if someone knows the correct way to get the name of a document in the workflow context.

I am working with Polarion ALM 18.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me in the document workflow context using:

```
var modulename = workflowContext.getTarget().getModuleName();
```